# Is there a word/concept for a word that denotes a place but is not a proper name?

Tags: terminology, toponomastics, toponyms

Is there a word/concept for a word that denotes a place but is not a proper name? As far as I understand toponyms are always proper nouns, so words such as "area", "playground", "hill" and "place" are not toponyms. Here and there I have seen the phrase "geographical common word". That is the closest I can come.

Comment: onomastics has tons of sub-categories. Just for water, check out the term hydronym: helonyms: proper names of swamps, marshes and bogs,[2]
limnonyms: proper names of lakes and ponds,[3]
oceanonyms: proper names of oceans,[4]
pelagonyms: proper names of seas and maritime bays,[5]
potamonyms: proper names of rivers and streams.[6] But they are all proper names.

Comment: I believe I have seen *generic* used for a part of a name that is also a common noun applicable to the named place; that is, in “Draper Avenue”, “Avenue” is the generic.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes we see metonymy, e.g., *the Valley* for "Silicon Valley". But I don't know any established term for recurring parts of geographical names ... maybe *topographical feature* for features like mountains, lakes, rivers, swamps, cities etc.